# In MacOSX Mavericks, launching an app from the command line versus by double-clicking

Tags: macos, command-line, environment-variables, gui

In MacOSX Mavericks, what are the differences between launching an app

1. by double-clicking it or through Spotlight, and
2. from the command line?

By launching an app such as Emacs from the command line, I mean, opening Terminal and typing

```
~$ open /Applications/Emacs.app
```

or

```
~$ /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs
```

I know the PATH environment variable can be different. But what else? And what's the consequence?

Also, what's the difference between Mavericks and, say, Snow Leopard?

Comment: Why do you assume there is a difference? Not sure if PATH is really different, but… what problem are you trying to solve? This question seems a little contrived to me, much like an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: See [my other question](http://superuser.com/questions/729329/auctex-view-works-or-does-not-depending-on-how-i-launched-emacs) for the reason why I assume there's a difference and why I'd like to find out what it is.

Comment: Sorry, but then that's still the same issue. The question here is vague and people would ask you for details about the problem anyway, so you'd end up with the question you already asked, where you give us all the info needed to solve your problem.

Comment: the open command has more options, including choosing what app to open a file with, and my fave: opening a new instance of an app even if another one is already running. See `man open` for more fun.